# HTML import by DART command

Tags: html, dom, import, dart

I read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/) about HTML import, and wanted to do same using dart

the 'import.html' file is:

```
<div id='imp'>This is the div to be imported</div>
```

the index.html file is:

```
the imported div shall appear here: <output id="imported-div"></output>
```

the main.dart file, is:

```
void main() {
      Element output = querySelector('#imported-div');

      var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
      var importedFile = link.import;

      output.innerHtml=importedFile.querySelector('div.imp');
   }
```

but nothing happened, and I do not know where shall I write the imported file name!! and if I need to write the below statement in the index.html file, or there is no need of it:

```
<link rel="import" href="import.html">
```

Any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor errors

The selector is wrong

```dart
// output.innerHtml=importedFile.querySelector('div.imp'); // requires <div class="imp">
//output.innerHtml=importedFile.querySelector('div#imp');  // requires <div id="imp">
output.append(importedFile.querySelector('div#imp'));      // append instead of innerHtml = (requires a String)
```

if you want to use the import more than once you can also do

```dart
output.append(importedFile.querySelector('div#imp').clone(true));
```

see also http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: I got this error msg in Chrome console, it look import not allowed in Chrome:

"Imported resource from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "

Comment: I think when you load this from files directly you need to start Chrome with this argument `--allow-file-access-from-files`